# Velocity does not register in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i was trying to make a 2D player walk around a "planet". But when players rotation reaches around 180 on the z, the player has the velocity but it is not applying.
here is the movement code

```
h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
rb2d.velocity = transform.right * speed * h;
```

(rb2d is rigidbody of my player and speed = 10)

and here is the code to rotate around the "planet"

```
    Vector2 upv = transform.up;
    Vector2 rightv = transform.right;
    
    Vector2 posL = transform.position * upv + DistFromCenter * rightv;
   
    RaycastHit2D leftr = Physics2D.Raycast(Pos1.transform.position, -upv,10f,playerL);
    RaycastHit2D rightr = Physics2D.Raycast(Pos2.transform.position, -upv,10f,playerL);
    


    if (leftr.point != Vector2.zero && rightr.point != Vector2.zero)
    {
        Vector2 _normal = (leftr.normal + rightr.normal) / 2;
        Vector2 _point = (leftr.point + rightr.point) / 2;

        Quaternion targetR = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector2.up, _normal);
        
        Quaternion ansRot = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetR, 1);
        

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, ansRot.eulerAngles.z);

       
    }
```

it just shoots two rays from each side of the character and rotates him using the hit info
(gravity is set to 0 on both x and y)

here is a image to understand better

[image]

Comment: You should read about [euler angles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) `When you read the .eulerAngles property, Unity converts the Quaternion's internal representation of the rotation to Euler angles. Because, there is more than one way to represent any given rotation using Euler angles, the values you read back out may be quite different from the values you assigned.` .. almost never want to read from that

Comment: I tried to use different ways to rotate(like in the article that you gave was said to try Quaternion * operator) but it did not help